# Connect The Wall-Words:

Tags: lateral-thinking, connect-wall

We have a group of 16 words here:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACIDITY | TIME | MICROSCOPE | MARKS |
| LIGHT | SCALE | CHEMISTRY | CLAW |
| REAL | LEAD | INTEREST | BIOLOGY |
| DUCK | RADICAL | ACADEMY | LEAF |

**Goal**: Group these $16$ words into $4$ groups, each group containing $4$ words. The words in every group should have a common theme. After completing the groups, choose one word from each group and they can again be grouped into a common theme. What is this Theme?

**Hint 1**:

> The positions of the words displayed above do not matter

**Hint 2**:

> All the words are related to Academic Studies, or are they?

**Hint 3**:

> One group will be "Marks, Claw, Real, Time". Proceed with this and try to find what common theme these words share...

Comment: are partial answers allowed?

Comment: In general partial answers to Connect Walls are accepted if they make [significant, verifiable progress](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6705/partial-answers-and-list-of-clues-puzzles) (i.e. three groups or two extremely solid ones). Askers can override that general rule for their own puzzles, of course.

Comment: The lateral thinking tag is an interesting facet...